# How to get the Android device screen size from the adb command line?

Tags: android, adb

I need a way to detect device screen size and density with adb. 
If there is no solution, where can I get the complete list of all existing android device with their screen size and density ?

Comment: If using Appium, you can use `Dimension windowSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();`.

Answer (score 129):

You can also access the WindowManager through ADB:

```
$ adb shell wm
usage: wm [subcommand] [options]
       wm size [reset|WxH]
       wm density [reset|DENSITY]
       wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]
```

To get the screen resolution:

```
$ adb shell wm size
Physical size: 2880x1600
```

To get the screen the density:

```
$ adb shell wm density
Physical density: 320
```

You can also override the density by adding the new density:

```
$ adb shell wm density 160
```

Answer (score 41):

LCD density is in the build.prop:

```bash
adb shell getprop ro.sf.lcd_density
```

And the resolution is availble in the dumpsys of the input activity:

```bash
# windows
adb shell dumpsys window | find "DisplayWidth"
# linux
adb shell dumpsys window | grep DisplayWidth
```

It works on all the devices I've tested with (2.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 4.0.3; Acer Liquid E, HTC Wildfire S, HTC Incredible S, Motorola Atrix 4G, Samsung Galaxy Note, Samsung Galaxy Nexus), as well as the emulator, although the emulator's outputs are *too clean to serve as a good example for parsing*.

Comment: There is also the min/max range of valid input coordinates for the event handlers that you can get using `getevent -p`. This is relevant in the cases where some of the touch input device is under the bezel, so the usable-minimum actually starts at some value greater than 0.

Comment: ro.sf.lcd_density doesn’t work for two devices I tried (GT-P7510 and Dell Streak), and works for 5 others (GT-P1000, Galaxy Nexus, MotoA953, DROID2 GLOBAL, Xoom)

Comment: If the above commands not working , try the command  adb shell dumpsys window | find "mUnrestrictedScreen"

Answer (score 27):

Using [`dumpsys`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys)

```
dumpsys window displays
```

shows something like this:

```
Display: mDisplayId=0
  init=1080x1920 480dpi cur=1080x1920 app=1080x1920 rng=1080x1005-1920x1845
  layoutNeeded=false
```

another way:

```
dumpsys display
```

also shows some interesting stuff like:

```
mDefaultViewport=DisplayViewport{valid=true, displayId=0, orientation=0, logicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920), physicalFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920), deviceWidth=1080, deviceHeight=1920}
```

and last but not least:

```
dumpsys power
```

will display something like

```
Electron Beam State:
  mPrepared=false
  mMode=2
  mDisplayLayerStack=0
  mDisplayWidth=1080
  mDisplayHeight=1920
  mSurfaceVisible=false
  mSurfaceAlpha=0.0
```

that you could easily use to grep for mDisplayWidth and mDisplayHeight

Answer (score 14):

To get required info from ADB, the following command executed from the command line will return a lot of useful properties about the connected devices

```
> adb shell getprop
```

To filter through these properties

on Unix use grep like

```
> adb shell getprop | grep density
```

on Windows use find like

```
> adb shell getprop | findstr "density"
```

Returned value looks like

```
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [240]
```

for screen size put display instead of density

Comment: and screen size doesn't appear

Comment: for screen size put display instead of density

Comment: Motorola Xoom, for example, doesn't show display informations

Comment: yeah I know, it's not for all devices.

Comment: Is **density** the same as **screen width**?

Answer (score 2):

```
ANDROID:/ # dumpsys window | grep mGlobalConfiguration                                                                                                                                                
mGlobalConfiguration={1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_US] ldltr sw720dp w1920dp h532dp 160dpi
```

So resolution is 1920x720

Answer (score 1):

Work is Good:

```bash
dumpsys window | grep Display
```

return: Display: init=320x480 cur=320x480 app=320x480 rng=320x295-480x455

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen dimensions with this code:

```java
public int getScreenHeight() {
    return getDisplay().getHeight();
}

private Display getDisplay() {
    return ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
}


public int getScreenWidth() {
    return getDisplay().getWidth();
}
```

Once you have the Display in the code above you can use [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to get the density. DisplayMetrics will also give you absolute display with and height.

Comment: I can't launch any application on devices.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the output of adb shell dumpsys. The screen size shows up there several times, along with lots of other information.

... although now I'm in the office, while it works on my phone, it's absent from the Galaxy tablet. Darn.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to get the current status of range of Android device available in the market with it [Screen Sizes and Densities Click here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)

This data is based on the number of Android devices that have accessed Android Market within a 7-day period ending on the data collection date

Comment: I need to get the screen size for particular device not all existing sizes.