# Get Maximum X and Y coordinates from Android Screen from command line

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to get the maxX and maxY coordinates on an android touch screen from command line? Are there any adb commands which would do the job for me. I'd be using these values to make a Python Script. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simple answer to your question is

```
adb shell dumpsys window | find "mUnrestrictedScreen"
```

Look in the note for link to the original Stack Overflow post where I got this from.

Comment: Found the original article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527459/android-device-screen-size

Answer (score 0):

I got it and would like to post the answer as it isn't answered.

Using adb shell getevent -p /dev/input/eventX - touchscreen event for the device, shall give you a series of results.

The one corresponding to 0035 gives maxX and 0036 gives maxY.