# Process.Start, passing single argument with spaces and vertical bar |

Tags: vb.net, windows, shell, adb, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass a single argument to adb.exe, which is

> shell dumpsys window | find "mUnrestrictedScreen"

However, the console returns

> find: mUnrestrictedScreen: No such file or directory

I assume that it is due to the spacing that I have in my argument, and they consider a different argument for every spacing. It reads just the back part of the whole argument:

> find "mUnrestrictedScreen"

And searches within my phone's file directory

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("Tools\adb.exe")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oStartInfo.Arguments = "shell dumpsys window | find ""mUnrestrictedScreen"" "
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
End Sub
```

I have tried just using this argument:

> shell dumpsys window

and it returns all the values correctly, but I need to narrow it down with find

> | find ""mUnrestrictedScreen""

But it just doesn't allow me to do so!

So the question is, how do I pass the whole argument as a single parameter?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I believe its not the spaces, but its more of the vertical bar that makes it pass 2 arguments instead of 1

Comment: You might want to move `oStartInfo.Arguments = ...` above `oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo`.

Comment: one way is to use string.format.  `myArgs = String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", Quote, argText)`  elsewhere define quote: `Private Quote As String = """"`

Comment: @TheBlueDog I just tried it, still the same problem...

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the suggestion, but still doesn't work. It just runs the adb without any arguments now. I notice there are double quotes encasing my string, but adb won't even read it

Comment: make sure you are using adb.exe correctly, but `StartInfo` will need the command line in quotes in order to pass that text as one single string arg rather than `shell`, `dumpsys`, `window`.  try without putting `mUnrestrictedScreen` in its own quote

Comment: @Plutonix Yes there are quotes on them, but the suggestion you gave outputs 2 quotes instead of one, 
Im not sure, now im suspecting it might be parsing 2 arguments and separates itself at the vertical bar |

Comment: quotes around the entire string *will* keep them together; whether that last word *needs* quotes or not, I cant say.  If it does, you need to quote it as well see https://dotnetfiddle.net/jhavqX#

Comment: @Plutonix Yes the last word needs quotes. I tried your suggestion but now it just omits the whole argument and simply runs adb.exe. I think it doesn't parse the argument if there are additional quotes surrounding it. I seriously suspect that the vertical bar is giving me problems and separating my arguments to 2 the quotes didn't help

Comment: Process doesnt omit it, more likely adb does because that last part is not a valid arg. this appears to be so as per this: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/how-to-use-adb-all-commands-and-options.6865/  you may need to capture the output from one task then feed it to another - or just use a batch file

Comment: @Plutonix I've tested the command using adb itself and it works. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527459/android-device-screen-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527459/android-device-screen-size) 
Thanks for the suggestions, in the end I decided to just output everything using `shell dumpsys window ` and parse it line by line to search for `mUnrestrictedScreen`. So far it works, but it is very inefficient, since I need to call this frequency to check the device's orientation and change my programs orientation accordingly

Comment: I don't think that `find` is an argument for adb.exe.  In a command shell, when you use a pipe like that, typically you are sending the output of one process (adb) into another (find).  In other words, `find` is a separate process.  So take the output from adb.exe and pass it into find.exe either on the command line or via the standard input.