# Adb Command to display size and density with devices running on version 4.2 or less not giving any result

Tags: android, adb

I am using android device with version 4.1.2 and aware of the fact that with the version below 4.3 has display size and density in am (Activity Manager) instead of wm (Windows Manager). We can also find it by using 'dumpsys' in some the devices by-

```
adb shell dumpsys display
```

But for the device I am using, it says-

```
Can't find service: display
```

And when I am checking the list of services for the devices by-

```
adb shell service list
```

It's showing display service is present as-

```
display.hwcservice: [android.display.IHWComposer]
```

But this service is giving no output.
Also by using am commands which is-

```
adb shell am display size <resolution>
```

We can only customize the resolution, but can't get the current resolution.

For devices running on version 4.3 or above, it can be determined by using-

```
adb shell wm size
adb shell wm density
```

Is there any other way to find out display size and density for devices running on 4.2 or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using dumpsys as-

```
adb shell dumpsys display
```

You can refer - [dumpsys illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527459/android-device-screen-size)

Comment: That outputs a whole lotta info.  Is there a way to concatenate it?

Comment: adb -s emulator-5554 shell wm size gives:
Physical size: 768x1280
Override size: 1200x1680 
Is there any way where we can directly get Physical/override size?

Answer (score 10):

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep cur= |tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 4|cut -d "=" -f 2
```